# In CyberSource, how do you use a credit card flexible token with payments API?

Tags: cybersource

Trying to get my head around how CyberSource works..

In CyberSource, the Secure Acceptance Flexible Token API can be used to tokenize a credit card on client-side for processing for future processing.

That part is easy enough. There's plenty of documentation and a few packages that do it.

How do I then use that token to create a charge with the CyberSource Payments API ?

All examples i've found show how to tokenize the card on client, and how to charge an untokenized card (i.e. card data is sent to server) but I can't find an example that show how to use the Flexible token to create a charge (or pre-auth).

In most other gateways like Stripe, it's pretty clear in documentations but CyberSource doesn't seem to provide that.

Am I missing something?

I'm using Node but happy with solutions in other languages.

https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#flex

https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/cybersource/reference

Comment: Did you check the Flex Developer Guide? https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/SAFlexibleToken.html

Comment: @rhldr Oh, woah.. I've checked all the docs and was looking for the reference to point out how it never explains how to use it specifically with the API and it actually does in this one..

Comment: The document @rhldr links to does not seem to have any data on *using* a token created with Flex.

Comment: @MattMc it does, it's kinda buried in it. See my answer below..

Comment: @Ben ah!  I see it now, thanks.  Not on the page he linked to, but on the one you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @rhldr for pointing out to this particular documentation.

The answer is in this page https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/SAFlexibleToken/FlexMicroform/GetStarted.html under "Using the Token".

Note: Some of the other documentations (not sure why they have some many variations of the docs), like [this one](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/hosted_flex/0_1_0/html/getting-started/#using-the-token) don't mention this at all.

See the RESTPaymentAPI section. It needs to be provided as a customerId field.

```
"paymentInformation": {
    "customer": {
        "customerId": "7500BB199B4270EFE05340588D0AFCAD"
    }
}
```

Here's a minimal example of how it can be implemented on the API side

```
var cybersourceRestApi = require('cybersource-rest-client');
var configuration = require('./cybersource/config.js');

var configObject = new configuration();
var instance = new cybersourceRestApi.PaymentsApi(configObject);

var clientReferenceInformation = new cybersourceRestApi.Ptsv2paymentsClientReferenceInformation();
clientReferenceInformation.code = 'test_payment';

var processingInformation = new cybersourceRestApi.Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation();
processingInformation.commerceIndicator = 'internet';

var amountDetails = new cybersourceRestApi.Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationAmountDetails();
amountDetails.totalAmount = "100.00";
amountDetails.currency = 'USD';

var orderInformation = new cybersourceRestApi.Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformation();
orderInformation.amountDetails = amountDetails;


var paymentInformation = new cybersourceRestApi.Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformation();

// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT
var customer = new cybersourceRestApi.Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformationCustomer()
customer.customerId = token
paymentInformation.customer = customer

var request = new cybersourceRestApi.CreatePaymentRequest();
request.clientReferenceInformation = clientReferenceInformation;
request.processingInformation = processingInformation;
request.orderInformation = orderInformation;
request.paymentInformation = paymentInformation;

if (!authoriseOnly) {
    request.processingInformation.capture = true;
}
```

Code based on the CyberSource nodejs REST samples: https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-samples-node

---

More info. Once you know where to look, it's actually explained in a few places.

Example, go to https://developer.cybersource.com/cybs-dev-api-ref/index.html#payments-process-a-payment, expand the "REQUEST FIELD DESCRIPTION" underneath and go to

```
customer         
    .. customerId
```

> Unique identifier for the customer's card
>   and billing information.
>
> When you use Payment Tokenization or Recurring Billing and you include
>   this value in your request, many of the fields that are normally
>   required for an authorization or credit become optional.
>
> NOTE When you use Payment Tokenization or Recurring Billing, the value
>   for the Customer ID is actually the Cybersource payment token for a
>   customer. This token stores information such as the consumer’s card
>   number so it can be applied towards bill payments, recurring payments,
>   or one-time payments. By using this token in a payment API request,
>   the merchant doesn't need to pass in data such as the card number or
>   expiration date in the request itself.
>
> See "Payment Tokenization," page 222, and "Recurring Billing," page
>   225.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I generated token in Cyber Source iOS SDK and the token is base 64 encoded string (very long). As you said, we need to mention token in Customer ID, I tried the same but it says invalid data. I can see your token is small and not base64 Encoded but mine is. So Can you please guide me how did you get this small payment token ?

Comment: @Deeps on Frontend i've used their Flex SDK to generate the key on the client side. I'm on web platform though, not iOS. I'm not sure what the equivalent is. The tokenisation of the card should happen from the client side, not your backend.